# CSS: Custom cursor sets back to default when hovered in BG

Tags: css, cursor, tumblr

I grabbed a Tumblr theme and modified it. Now my problem is that the custom cursor works in the body but when I hover it on the background, it changes to the default cursor.. I hope you could help with this one. Thanks in advance! ^_^

For the code I used, please [click here](http://laboumph.tumblr.com/) to be directed on my Tumblr. Right click and select "view page source".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add following CSS and it works fine

```
* {
    cursor: url(http://static.tumblr.com/xjqjg7j/UJ8mxtr2b/01.png), url(http://static.tumblr.com/xjqjg7j/UJ8mxtr2b/01.png), auto;
}
```

or

```
html{
    cursor: url(http://static.tumblr.com/xjqjg7j/UJ8mxtr2b/01.png), url(http://static.tumblr.com/xjqjg7j/UJ8mxtr2b/01.png), auto;
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't able to accept it right away. There was an error last night but it worked now. Thanks again! ^_^